# What is the difference between returning an arrow function vs function declaration in Debounce?

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions

While learning about Debounce in JS, I've seen 2 different approaches. Is there a difference between calling the callback within the function declaration example vs calling with apply binding within the arrow function example?

```
function debounce(cb, delay) {
   let timeoutId;
   return function(...args) {
       clearTimeout(timeoutId)
       timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
           cb(args)
       }, delay);
   }
}
```

VS

```
function debounce(func, delay){
   let timeoutId;
   return (...args) => {
       clearTimeout(timeoutId);
       timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
          func.apply(this, args);
       }, delay);
   };
}
```

Comment: those are not the same functionality. And that second one does no debouncing....

Comment: oops, sorry I just edited it!

Comment: Is your question about the difference between arrow functions and functions declared using the `function` keyword? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable for instance.

Comment: I'm trying to confirm whether they are identical in all use cases, or is one flawed (returning the function declaration, probably). If both examples are the same, I guess I want to really look at it to figure how they're the same.

Comment: They are not equivalent. `func.apply(this, args)` is obviously different from `cb(args)` (which should've been `cb(...args)` btw) in the presence of a non-`undefined` value of `this`.